# Is there a hotkey or shortcut to upgrade all units?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

At certain points in the game, a variety of upgrades become available to your existing units.  Unfortunately this produces a really tedious management issue, where the user has to select each individual unit and click on each type of upgrade.  [Some people mentioned](http://steamcommunity.com/app/214950/discussions/0/864978762470945693/) that you can upgrade multiple units at a time, but either it doesn't work or they have to be the same unit.

Is there a hotkey or shortcut for quickly applying upgrades to units?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade them all by clicking on your army, of course, and then select all units with `ctrl + A` and after that hover over any unit, the `upgrade or disband` tooltip will appear, and select upgrade, like you were doing when upgrading a unit. It will even show the total amount for upgrading all units.